# Check a previous checkbox when focus on Other textbox?

Tags: jquery, input

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#Q4_5other").focus(function() {
        $(this).prev().prop("checked", True);
    });
});
```

I am attempting to 'check' a checkbox once someone begins to type in the Other text field. Could someone share with me the best practice for doing this? Thanks.

Comment: True should be lowercase true. You may want to test the value on blur too

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qtjskwwo/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L7j15kwd/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the correction. It's a textbox for a checkbox that has 'other' as an option. I see these all the time but I'm having the biggest issue getting the above checkbox to check on focus or blur. It just doesn't work.

Comment: Not getting you what exactly you want plz share your html also.

Comment: Example Survey: See Question 2 or 3

http://whadev.com/mf/dc/survey.html

Comment: yes i have seen the link..just visit the link of fiddle i have given above it will work in your scenario.

Comment: @Kartikeya here is my problem, getting past the labels... http://jsfiddle.net/L7j15kwd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered questioner question in comments section just below the question now questioner extended the question so I m posting answer here.

Try to bind multiple events `'focus ,blur, keyup'` as shown :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Q4_5other").on('focus blur keyup', function()() {
        $(this).prev().prop("checked", $.trim($(this).val()) != "");       
    });
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7j15kwd/1/)

EDIT :- As per questioner comment (input fields are inside label) try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#Q4_5other").on('focus blur keyup', function() {
      $(this).prev().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked",$.trim($(this).val()) != "");    
   });
});
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7j15kwd/5/)

**NOTE :- As questioner has not given the DOM structure so I m just posting answer as per the website link given in comments below the question.**

Comment: @chrisb ... I think this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I deeply appreciate your time and your expertise.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following: check when enter but test the value when leaving or editing content

```
 $(function() {
  $("#Q4_5other")
    .on('focus', function() {
       $(this).prev().prop("checked", true);
    })
    .on('blur keyup', function() {
      $(this).prev().prop("checked", $.trim(this.value)!="");
});
```

Comment: its `keyup` not `ketup`.

Comment: Thanks. On my phone at 6am

Comment: @mplungjan Here is my problem, getting this to work with the input wrapped in label tags http://jsfiddle.net/L7j15kwd/

Comment: @mplungjan the HTML is in the HTML pane...? Am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/L7j15kwd/

Comment: Yes. You say you have issues with labels. So add the labels Show the HTML you need to fix! I am off to bed. I see you already accepted a solution. I would use $("#Q4_5other").closest(".container").find... since I did not know your HTML

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qtjskwwo/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").keyup(function() {
       // alert('d');
       $(this).prev("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);;
    });
});
```

Comment: always put some explanation to the answer you posted, so that others can get it easily.

Comment: Ok I am new here. Thanks for the suggestion :)